# Array return 0 length, unable to call it in html

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am calling ticketCountData in html, but it returns nothing, the reason is that array length is 0.

result - main array with all data,

In bellow script I am checking how many times unique names appears in the array and I return the number of it:

```
result.forEach((row) => {
    if(!(row['Owner'] in ticketCountData))
        ticketCountData[row['Owner']] = 0;

    ticketCountData[row['Owner']] += 1;

})
console.log(ticketCountData);
```

Array shows correct data, yet it length is 0. I can check length of it by

```
console.log(Object.keys(ticketCountData).length);
```

Yet I am not sure how to call value that is in the array, which looks like that:

```
Array(0)
"": 10
john.smith1: 18
john.smith2: 13
john.smith3: 21
john.smith4: 24
```

Thanks!

Comment: `ticketCountData` isn't an array, it's an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that your ticketCountData is NOT an array - it is an object. The square brackets in javascript can be used in different ways, specifically you need to know that these two expressions are identical:

```
ob.name='andrew';
ob['name']='andrew';
```

So your code runs perfectly but produces an object that has unique names as a key and the count as values.
Generally to turn this into an array containing the name and the count you would do something like this:

```
let countDataList=Object.keys(ticketCountData).map((key)=> ({
       name:key,
       count: ticketCountData[key],
   }))
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the function `hasOwnProperty` of JS.

```js
result.forEach((row) => {
    if(!ticketCountData.hasOwnProperty(row['Owner']) ){
        ticketCountData[row['Owner']] = 0;
    }

    ticketCountData[row['Owner']] += 1;
})

console.log(ticketCountData);
```

Comment: Be careful when  using `includes` on array, it is [not compatible with every browser](https://caniuse.com/#feat=array-includes)

Comment: hi @mhSangar, Welcome to SO. I think you answer falls into the same trap that the original poster fell into of thinking that ticketCountData is an array - it is a standard object and as such inlcudes won't work on it.

Comment: Hi @Elemental, thanks for your comment ^^ I updated my answer to use `hasOwnProperty` function, as it is an object, not an array